# css navigation menu problem in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, navigation

hi I have written css code to display menu bar. faced so many issues googled them and found solution too. But this one I couldn't find.
This is chrome output which has gaps in betweens menu boxes but if firefox theres no issue at all. its contact. how do I solve this?

CSS

```
#candymenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8.1em;
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    height: 3em;
}
#candymenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 153px;

}   


#candymenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin 150px;    
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#candymenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 8.1em;
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    height: 3em;
    border-right: 1px #818181 solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px  #bbb;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px  1px #bbb;
}

#candymenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .8em .5em .5em .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #292929;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cccccc;
}

#candymenu li {
    background-color: #c9c9c9;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#c9c9c9),    to(#848484), color-stop(0.6, #a1a1a1));
}

#candymenu li:hover {
    background-color: #dc3d73;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dc3d73), to(#4c4c4c), color-stop(0.6, #474747));
}

#candymenu li:hover a {
    color: #e8e8e8;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #353535;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="candymenu">    
    <ul>
        <li id="home">
            <a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li id="Gaming">
            <a href="">Gaming</a></li>
        <li id="Reviews">
            <a href="">Reviews</a></li>
        <li id="News">
            <a href="">news</a></li>
        <li id="Interviews">
            <a href="">interviews</a></li>
        <li id="download">
            <a href="">Download</a> </li>
        <li id="support">
            <a href="">Support</a></li>
        <li id="candy">
            <a href="">Candy</a></li>
        <li id="events">
            <a href="">Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

now how do i reduce that gap?

Comment: theres "border-right 1px" i removed that and the gap reduced but still there is white gap in between ( though small ). Plus the whole menu is fine in ff but in chrome its a little left shifted which doesn't look good.. reason? any cross browser css code which will not be problem in any browser once written?

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? Or, add a screenshot pointing out which gap you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think inline-block results in white-space dependent layout, which sucks.

So you basically need to place all your li-tags back to back, on one single line. Like so:

```
<div id="candymenu">    
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="">Home</a></li><li id="Gaming"><a href="">Gaming</a></li>
```

etc.

Let me know if it works out!

Comment: worked.. :) but in ff its fine.. and in chrome it shifts a little away from left....

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/VXsmd/
Change the `display:inline-block` of both `#candymenu li` and `#candymenu li a` to be `display:block` and then add `float:left` to each as well. That seems to have fixed it in the provided Fiddle.

Comment: Yes that's what I was going to suggest. horizontal lists should be done with `display: block` and `float: left` rather than `display: inline-block` because of the spacing problem. If you need the parent item to expand to the height of the child items instead of collapsing (a common reason for using `inline-block`) toggle this with `overflow: auto` or another clearfix solution instead: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html